# Can't connect my listview to the searchbar, what am I missing?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I have created a list view with my database (using the database parse) and it works perfectly fine. the items shows up on my list view but when i insert a search bar to it and try to connect them together the search bar doesn't seem to find the list with the items (i have it there so i can filter between the things in the list). anyone know what the problem might be with my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ListCode
{
        public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
        {
                List<createSomething> ourPitems = new List<createSomething>();


            public StartPage ()
            {
                    InitializeComponent ();
                    sbSearch.TextChanged += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(sbSearch.Text);
                    sbSearch.SearchButtonPressed += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(sbSearch.Text);

            }

            private  void FilterContacts (string filter)
            {
                    EmployeeList.BeginRefresh ();

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (filter)) {
                            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;
                    } else {
                            //EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems.Contains (filter.ToLower ());
                    }

                    EmployeeList.EndRefresh ();
            }


    async void loadOurItem () //hittar våra items
            {
                    var getItems = await parseAPI.getOurMainInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString ());

                    EmployeeList.ItemsSource = null;
                    ourPitems = new List<createSomething> ();

                    foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"])
                    {
                            ourPitems.Add (new createSomething ()
                            {
                                    info1 = currentItem ["listName"].ToString (),
                                    info2 = currentItem ["objectId"].ToString (),
                            });    
                    }
               EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;
            }




public class createSomething

            {

                    public string info1 {get; set;}
                    public string info2 {get; set;}

            }


   }


}
```

Comment: please take the time to paste the relevant portions of your code into the item and format it properly.  Linking to offsite resources is discouraged

Comment: sry, first time i post something myself here. i just got errors when i copied my code directly.

Comment: you are not calling loadOurItem(), so you list will never contain data.

Comment: damn, i left that out :( 
haha sry. i have this as well,
the problem is not the data because it is there and it works, the problem is that the searchbar doesnt connect with the data ;

protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
   if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("userId") == false) {
    Navigation.PushModalAsync (new LoginPage ());
   } else {

    loadOurItem ();
    

   }

  }

Comment: is FilterItems() being fired?  Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: Ah, it is not. Should I add it in my OnAppearing func and load it the same way as "loadOurItem"?, I do not know how to debugg as of now. I have been programming for 2months only so im very new.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_in_xamarin_ios/